# Form reset issue after get response via API in react js

Tags: forms, reactjs

I am submitting form via redux API call and getting response but on success response I am trying to reset form but that giving issue  -

`setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within`render`or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to 'componentWillMount'.`

here is my from file  -

=========================

```
import React from 'react'; 
import DefaultLayout from '../Layout/DefaultLayout';
//import $ from 'jquery';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'; 
import { contactRequest } from '../actions/signupActions';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import  validator from 'validator';



class Contactus extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        document.title = "Contact Us";

        this.errorMapping = {"100": "Your message has been submitted.",
        "102": "Name cannot be empty.",
        "104": "Email cannot be empty.",
        "103": "Hotel cannot be empty.",
        "105": "Incorrect email format.",
        "106": "Phone cannot be empty."}

        this.state = {name: '',email:'',message :''};

        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this); 
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this); 

        this.baseState = this.state 
    }


    handleInputChange(event) {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.contactRequest(this.state);
    }


    render(){
        const style_1 = {height: '240px'};
        const style_2 = {marginRight: '15px'};
        const style_3 = {width: 'auto'};

        return(
            <DefaultLayout>
                <section id="content">
                    <div className="content-wrap">
                        <div className="container clearfix">

                            <div className="col-md-6 bottommargin">
                                <section id="google-map" className="gmap" style={style_1} ></section>
                            </div>

                            <div className="col-md-6">

                                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contactFormModal" className="button button-3d nomargin btn-block button-xlarge hidden-xs center">Click here to Send an Email</a>
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contactFormModal" className="button button-3d nomargin btn-block visible-xs center">Send an Email</a>

                                <div className="modal fade" id="contactFormModal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="contactFormModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div className="modal-dialog">
                                        <div className="modal-content">

                                            <div className="modal-body">

                                                <div className="contact-widget">
                                                        <div className="contact-form-result">
                                                            {this.props.resultMessage && this.props.resultMessage.status.map((msg, idx) => { 
                                                                     if(msg === 100) { 
                                                                        this.setState({name : "",email : ""});
                                                                        return <span key={idx} id="succ_msg">{this.errorMapping[msg]}</span>
                                                                     } else {
                                                                        return <span key={idx} id="err_msg">{this.errorMapping[msg]}</span>
                                                                    }
                                                                })
                                                            }
                                                        </div>
                                                    <form className="nobottommargin" id="r_contactform" name="r_contactform" method="post" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} ref={(el) => this.myFormRef = el} >

                                                        <div className="form-process"></div>

                                                        <div className="col_half">
                                                            <label htmlFor="template-contactform-name">Name <small>*</small></label>
                                                            <input type="text" id="template-contactform-name" name="name" value={this.state.name} className="sm-form-control required" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div className="col_half col_last">
                                                            <label htmlFor="template-contactform-email">Email <small>*</small></label>
                                                            <input type="email" id="template-contactform-email" name="email" value={this.state.email} className="required email sm-form-control" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div className="clear"></div>


                                                        <div className="clear"></div>

                                                        <div className="col_half">
                                                            <label htmlFor="template-contactform-message">Message <small>*</small></label>
                                                            <textarea className="required sm-form-control" id="template-contactform-message" name="message"  value={this.state.message} rows="6" cols="30" onChange={this.handleInputChange}></textarea>
                                                            <span className={this.state.messageError ? 'help-block error': '' }>{ this.state.messageError ? this.state.messageError: '' }</span>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div className="col_full">
                                                            <button className="button button-3d nomargin" type="submit" id="contactform-submit" name="contactform-submit">Send Message</button>
                                                        </div>

                                                    </form>

                                                </div>


                                            </div>
                                            <div className="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </section>

            </DefaultLayout>
        );  
    }
}


function mapStateToProps(state){
    console.log("View data :"+JSON.stringify(state.Contactdata));
    return { 
        resultMessage: state.Contactdata
    }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return bindActionCreators({contactRequest: contactRequest}, dispatch)
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (Contactus);
```

getting response in `mapStateToProps` function and trying to update state where I have applied condition `if(msg === 100)` .

Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right place to setState is not in the map function, since you are receiving props from redux, you can do it in the componentWillReceiveProps fucntion

```
class Contactus extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        document.title = "Contact Us";

        this.errorMapping = {"100": "Your message has been submitted.",
        "102": "Name cannot be empty.",
        "104": "Email cannot be empty.",
        "103": "Hotel cannot be empty.",
        "105": "Incorrect email format.",
        "106": "Phone cannot be empty."}

        this.state = {name: '',email:'',message :''};

        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this); 
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this); 

        this.baseState = this.state 
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
           nextProps.resultMessage.status.forEach((msg, idx) => { 
                if(msg === 100) { 
                    this.setState({name : "",email : ""});
                 }
          }           
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.contactRequest(this.state);
    }


    render(){
        const style_1 = {height: '240px'};
        const style_2 = {marginRight: '15px'};
        const style_3 = {width: 'auto'};

        return(
            <DefaultLayout>
                <section id="content">
                    <div className="content-wrap">
                        <div className="container clearfix">

                            <div className="col-md-6 bottommargin">
                                <section id="google-map" className="gmap" style={style_1} ></section>
                            </div>

                            <div className="col-md-6">

                                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contactFormModal" className="button button-3d nomargin btn-block button-xlarge hidden-xs center">Click here to Send an Email</a>
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contactFormModal" className="button button-3d nomargin btn-block visible-xs center">Send an Email</a>

                                <div className="modal fade" id="contactFormModal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="contactFormModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div className="modal-dialog">
                                        <div className="modal-content">

                                            <div className="modal-body">

                                                <div className="contact-widget">
                                                        <div className="contact-form-result">
                                                            {this.props.resultMessage && this.props.resultMessage.status.map((msg, idx) => { 
                                                                     if(msg === 100) { 

                                                                        return <span key={idx} id="succ_msg">{this.errorMapping[msg]}</span>
                                                                     } else {
                                                                        return <span key={idx} id="err_msg">{this.errorMapping[msg]}</span>
                                                                    }
                                                                })
                                                            }
                                                        </div>
                                                    <form className="nobottommargin" id="r_contactform" name="r_contactform" method="post" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} ref={(el) => this.myFormRef = el} >

                                                        <div className="form-process"></div>

                                                        <div className="col_half">
                                                            <label htmlFor="template-contactform-name">Name <small>*</small></label>
                                                            <input type="text" id="template-contactform-name" name="name" value={this.state.name} className="sm-form-control required" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div className="col_half col_last">
                                                            <label htmlFor="template-contactform-email">Email <small>*</small></label>
                                                            <input type="email" id="template-contactform-email" name="email" value={this.state.email} className="required email sm-form-control" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div className="clear"></div>


                                                        <div className="clear"></div>

                                                        <div className="col_half">
                                                            <label htmlFor="template-contactform-message">Message <small>*</small></label>
                                                            <textarea className="required sm-form-control" id="template-contactform-message" name="message"  value={this.state.message} rows="6" cols="30" onChange={this.handleInputChange}></textarea>
                                                            <span className={this.state.messageError ? 'help-block error': '' }>{ this.state.messageError ? this.state.messageError: '' }</span>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div className="col_full">
                                                            <button className="button button-3d nomargin" type="submit" id="contactform-submit" name="contactform-submit">Send Message</button>
                                                        </div>

                                                    </form>

                                                </div>


                                            </div>
                                            <div className="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </section>

            </DefaultLayout>
        );  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the reason, you are doing `setState` inside `render` method:

```
{this.props.resultMessage && this.props.resultMessage.status.map((msg, idx) => { 
      if(msg === 100) { 
         this.setState({name : "",email : ""});
         .....
```

When **msg==100** will be true, you are doing `setState`, again it will trigger `re-rendering`, again `setState` ....... **infinite loop**.

Remove that `setState` it will work.

Use **[componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)** lifecycle method, and do the `setState` inside that.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    newProps.resultMessage.status.forEach((msg, idx) => { 
         if(msg === 100) { 
              this.setState({
                  name : "",
                  email : ""
              });
         }
    }           
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply mayank, but If i remove `this.setState({name : "",email : ""});` error will gone but how can I reset the form , where should I apply this ?